# Получить первое слово строки типа string (не "с") на с++

Tags: c++, строки

Это "первое слово" должно после выполнения программы находится в другой переменной, например:

---

```
string usersWords, firstWord;
getline(cin, usersWords);
usersWords = " " + usersWords + " ";
```

---

...
в переменной ***firstWord*** должно содержаться первое слово.
В начале и в конце строки стоят пробелы это для упрощения моей задачи, так уж надо.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, простейший вариант -

```
istringstream(usersWords) >> firstWord;
```